# Ionic2/3 - header button icon has different size then auto back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic's 2/3 auto button when using NavController.

On one of the pages I want to add button to the header, which will change something, so I've added it:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="orange">
    <ion-title>Test</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-right clear (click)="openModal()">
        Next <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Unfortunately, size of the icon is slightly different (smaller) then Back button added automatically by the Ionic.
I know that I can style it with CSS but I am afraid to break something (I can't test all the devices).

Screenshot (both Android & iOS):
[image: right button's icon is smaller then back icon]
[image: same for iOS]

Maybe should I use different button classes or components?
How can I make size of all buttons & icons in header the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use icon-only directive and that's all. This way is back-button.

```
<ion-buttons end>
   <button ion-button icon-right icon-only clear (click)="openModal()">
      Next <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
   </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Comment: This is actually the _most Ionic way_ to solve the issue. +1

Answer (score 1):

You just need to increase the `font-size` of the `icon` as shown below.

**Note:** Hence you're doing this inside your page's `scss` file it **will not** break any other default styles.

*your-page.scss*

```
.icon[name="arrow-forward"] {
        font-size: 2.4rem;; //same size of the default back button
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a `next-button` class to your icon.

```
<ion-icon name="arrow-forward" class="next-button"></ion-icon>
```

Refer to the ionic source code to get the exact [CSS rules for the back button](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/a30379bef6bf323b512b12eeb6904abab4690115/src/components/toolbar/toolbar.ios.scss). Then add your custom styles accordingly.

```
ion-icon.next-button.icon-ios {
    min-width: 18px;
    font-size: 3.4rem;
    padding-left: inherit;
    text-align: right;    
    display: inline-block;
}

ion-icon.next-button.icon-md {  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 6px;
    text-align: right;   
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```